# Add single quotes to shell variable substitution in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline that's trying to interact with google api. In that pipeline, I have to make some api calls but the data in those calls is variable, since it relies on fetching access token from google.

```
void uploadT(access_token, FILE_NAME, ITEM_ID){
    echo 'uploading'
    script{
        echo FILE_NAME
        String path = pwd() + '/xyz.zip'
        if(fileExists(path)){
            echo 'file exists'
        }else{
            echo 'no file found'
        }
        String response = sh ("curl --verbose -H 'Authorization: Bearer $access_token' -H 'x-goog-api-version: 2' -X PUT -T '$path' -v https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$ITEM_ID")
        echo response
        def parsedResponse = sh(script : "node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).uploadState' '$response'", returnStdout: true)
        echo parsedResponse
        if(parsedResponse != "SUCCESS"){
            //error('Failing build because of failed upload')
        }
    }
}
```

Here the important line with the api call

```
String response = sh ("curl --verbose -H 'Authorization: Bearer $access_token' -H 'x-goog-api-version: 2' -X PUT -T '$path' -v https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$ITEM_ID")
```

In this after substitution the single quotes around Authorization or api version or path disappear. API calls this way always fail for me but if I put in the text instead of the variables, the calls work fine.  Due to version constraints, I can't rely on plugins. Need to do it shell. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use ${VAR_Name} syntax? try  `"curl --verbose -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}' -H 'x-goog-api-version: 2' -X PUT -T '${path}' -v https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$ITEM_ID")`

Comment: @Mike Just tried it and no substitution took place.Here is the output "curl --verbose -H Authorization: Bearer ${access_token} -H x-goog-api-version: 2 -X PUT -T ${path}"